# No implicit conversion of Array into String?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application with the following GET method that takes the URL passed in:

```
get  %r{/html/(.+)}  do 
  url = params[:captures] # stores url => http://www.example.com

  gethtml(url)
end
```

However, when `gethtml(url)` is called, it raises the error `Sinatra no implicit conversion of Array into String`.

`gethtml` accepts input such as `http://example.com`.

I know this is a data-type conversion issue and I tried calling `to_s` but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params[:captures]` returns an array of strings, while `get_html` most likely accepts one URL as string.

Since you want to use the first group that matches as the URL:

```
get %r|/html/(.+)| do
  get_html params[:captures].first
end
```

This is consistent with the *Route matching with Regular Expressions* example in [the *Routes* section of the `README`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes).